# Removing user object on socket disconnect causes error in main loop

Tags: javascript, sockets, socket.io

I have a game that has a main loop that goes something like:

```
for (var i = 0; i < users.length; ++i) {
    users[i].value--;
    if (users[i].value) {

    }
}
```

And the users is connected via a socket:

```
io.on('connect', function(socket) {
    var tmpUser = {};
    users.push(tmpUser);
    socket.on('disconnect', function() {
        users.splice(users.indexOf(tmpUser), 1)
    });
})
```

Sometimes when a user disconnects it causes an error saying:

```
Cannot read property .value of undefined
```

I think this maybe be because the disconnect is asynchronous. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would guess that something in `.doSomething()` is changing the `users` data structure such that `users[i]` is no longer value after running `.doSomething()`.

You could fix that by change this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < users.length; ++i) {
    users[i].doSomething();
    users[i].doAnother();
}
```

to this:

```
var user;
for (var i = 0; i < users.length; ++i) {
    user = users[i];
    user.doSomething();
    user.doAnother();
}
```

Or switching to `.forEach()` instead of your `for` loop.

Comment: I have updated the question. The functions basically do what I have added

Comment: @SidneydeVries - So you just changed the question to different code.  I guess I wasted my time trying to help.